# How to get all returned data from all ajax calls when all done?

Tags: jquery, promise

I have two jquery ajax calls.
After all calls are complete, I want to get both returned data.
For the example purpose both return "num".
Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var allPromises = [
        $.ajax({url: '/ajax.php', method: 'post', data: {num: 1}}),
        $.ajax({url: '/ajax.php', method: 'post', data: {num: 2}})
    ];

    $.when.apply($, allPromises).done(function(returnData) {
        console.log(returnData);
    });
});
```

For instance, I want to get sum of the returned values.
The problem is that I am getting data only from the first request.
How can I do it without saving in global variable?

Comment: Seems to work, doesn't it?

Comment: You use the data inside the `.done()` handler right where you have the `console.log(returnData)`.  That's the only place in your code where you know the timing is correct to use the data.  If you want to sum the data, you sum it right there.

Comment: @Bergi The problem is that I am getting data only from one request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a return value for each promise:

```
$.when.apply($, allPromises).done(function(returnData1, returnData2) {
    console.log(returnData1);
    console.log(returnData2);
});
```

see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

For an unknown number of ajax calls you can use:

```
$.when.apply($, allPromises).then(function() {
    var objects = arguments; // The array of resolved objects as a pseudo-array
    ...
};
```

Comment: Great answer!
But what if I don't know allPromises.length?

Comment: What about `arguments` then?

Comment: I updated the answer.